# Listen to database changes in every Azure Function App instance

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

In my Azure function, I'm using a library which caches some state in memory. I need to clear this cache when data in a CosmosDB collection changes. At a first look, it may seem like I could use an input binding to listen to CosmosDB changes and then just clear the cache.

But I don't think this works under load. The function app will be scaled, so there can be multiple instances. And from what I understand, CosmosDB events from the input binding will only be sent to one instance, not to all instances. The same is true for functions on a schedule. Only one instance is targeted.

How can I notify all instances, so that they can clear their state? I know every instance could manually poll the database, but that causes a lot of overhead. Is there a better way?

PS: Not sure if it matters, but I'm using NodeJS.

Comment: Is each of your instances an independent Function App?

Comment: No, this is one app, but Azure will scale it out (start multiple instances in parallel) under load. I have no control over this, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

using distributed cache, e.g. Redis, by using its SDK from Function code is probably the best way to cache data  - that way the cached value is shared between all instances, and doesn't rely on the Azure functions runtime reusing the same machine for all function calls
its managed by Microsoft is highly scalable and provides super fast access to data.

**Reference**: https://crmazurecomponents.wordpress.com/2018/08/11/caching-in-azure-functions/

Comment: I would still have to pull (query the cache for updates), right? Or is there a way for Redis to notify all function instances when a value is modified?

Comment: Since it is a distributed cache, you need to always update and pull the content from the redis. Read below blog for reference:

https://medium.com/asos-techblog/synchronising-azure-cosmos-db-into-redis-cache-using-azure-functions-621d00813ccf

Comment: @restfulhead how will you target a call to a _particular_ instance of the function app? there is no way that is possible. Even today[in Q3 2023] there is no way to ensure to notify to **all** running instances of a function app, and I doubt if it will ever be. The function app code need to check the distributed cache or a marker stored in some central location[say blob store, etc].

Comment: Right, I also came to the conclusion that it is not possible to notify all function instances. I understand that I can manually check a cache such as Redis; that wasn't the question/issue.